# RxSwift renew Authentication Token

Tags: swift, oauth, rx-swift, moya

Hy I'm trying to come up with a solution using Moya and RxSwift that renews an Authentication token and retries the requests.

The problem is I have multiple requests going on at the same time, so lets say 10 requests fire while the Authentication token has expired, I will try to renew the token on all of them, and as soon as the first one renews the other ones will fail because they use a wrong token to renew.

What I would like to do is just build a queue (maybe) of requests and then retry those. Not sure if this is the best scenario for this.

This is what I have so far:

```
final class NetworkOnlineProvider {

    fileprivate let database = DatabaseClient(database: DatabaseRealm()).database
    fileprivate let provider: MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>

    init(endpointClosure: @escaping MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>.EndpointClosure = MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>.defaultEndpointMapping,
         requestClosure: @escaping MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>.RequestClosure = MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>.defaultRequestMapping,
         stubClosure: @escaping MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>.StubClosure = MoyaProvider.neverStub,
         manager: Manager = MoyaProvider<NetworkAPI>.defaultAlamofireManager(),
         plugins: [PluginType] = [],
         trackInflights: Bool = false) {

        self.provider = MoyaProvider(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, requestClosure: requestClosure, stubClosure: stubClosure, manager: manager, plugins: plugins, trackInflights: trackInflights)
    }

    fileprivate func getJWTRenewRequest() -> Single<Response>? {
        if let token = JWTManager.sharedInstance.token {

            return provider.rx.request(.renew(token: token))
        }

        return nil
    }

    func tokenRequest() -> Single<String> {
        let errorSingle = Single<String>.create { single in
            single(.error(APIError.failure))

            return Disposables.create()
        }

        let emptyJWTSingle = Single<String>.create { single in
            single(.success(""))

            return Disposables.create()
        }

        // Return if no token found
        guard let appToken = JWTManager.sharedInstance.getJWT() else {
            return refreshToken() ?? emptyJWTSingle
        }

        // If we have a valid token, just return it
        if !appToken.hasTokenExpired {
            return Single<String>.create { single in
                single(.success(appToken.token))

                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }

        // Token has expired
        let newTokenRequest = refreshToken()
        return newTokenRequest ?? errorSingle
    }

    func refreshToken() -> Single<String>? {
        return getJWTRenewRequest()?
            .debug("Renewing JWT")
            .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            .map { (response: Response) -> (token: String, expiration: Double) in
                guard let json = try? JSON(data: response.data) else { throw RxError.unknown }

                let success = json["success"]

                guard
                    let jwt = success["jwt"].string,
                    let jwt_expiration = success["jwt_expiration"].double,
                    let valid_login = success["valid_login"].bool, valid_login
                    else { throw RxError.unknown }

                return (token: jwt, expiration: jwt_expiration)
            }
            .do(onSuccess: { (token: String, expiration: Double) in
                JWTManager.sharedInstance.save(token: JWT(token: token, expiration: String(expiration)))
            })
            .map { (token: String, expiration: Double) in
                return token
            }
            .catchError { e -> Single<String> in
                print("Failed to Renew JWT")
                JWTManager.sharedInstance.delete()

                UIApplication.shared.appDelegate.cleanPreviousContext(jwt: true)
                let loginVC = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .login).instantiateViewController(vc: LoginViewController.self)
                UIApplication.shared.appDelegate.window?.setRootViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC))

                throw e
            }
    }

    func request(_ target: NetworkAPI) -> Single<Response> {
        let actualRequest = provider.rx.request(target)

        if target.isAuthenticatedCall {
            return tokenRequest().flatMap { _ in
                actualRequest
            }
        }


        return actualRequest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here: [RxSwift and Retrying a Network Request Despite Having an Invalid Token](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29)

The key is to use flatMapFirst so you only make one request for the first 401 and ignore other 401s while that request is in flight.

The gist associated with the article includes unit tests proving it works.